# Analytical Solution of 2D Eikonal equation $u_x^2 + u_y^2 =1$ in a square boundary

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading a lecture script in the following link:
[https://people.cam.cornell.edu/~zc227/extras/math6200_pres.pdf](https://people.cam.cornell.edu/%7Ezc227/extras/math6200_pres.pdf)

About the solution of example 1.1, I know the general solution of Eikonal equation is $u(x,y) = ax + \sqrt{1-a^2} y + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants determined from boundary conditions. It can be obtained by separation variables or characteristics method. But since the boundaries have some points like $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$ are undifferentiated. I have no idea how $a$ and $b$ can be determine from region $[0,1]^2$. My questions are:

(a) how to implement such a square boundary $[0,1]^2$ to determine the solution (especially for $a$ and $b$) to obtain the pyramid shape in Figure 1.

(b) Why the vertex point in Figure 1 is $u(0.5,0.5) = 0.5$?

Thank you!